# Need help summing unit weights and a multi-level parts list

Tags: vba, excel, sum, conditional-statements

This is what I'm trying to do with my current code [image]

And here is my excel https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GLuBx-ROnhRExUM2xVbG1WOTQ/edit?usp=sharing

The loop checks if the part level indicates it is a parent assembly (the level is lower than the one beneath). Then it sums all the child parts/assemblies Unit Weights below it ( a child part has no other parts beneath it). I don't have much programming experience, so I'm not sure why this isn't working or if its even the best approach.

```
Sub UpdateUnitWeight()
Const StartRow = 2
Dim oRng As Range ' Range to work on
Dim oRngSP As Range ' Range for SumProduct
Dim lRows As Long ' Counter
' Start from row "StartRow"
Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartRow, "A")
'Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
' Loop on numeric cells from StartRow
Do Until IsEmpty(oRng) Or Not IsNumeric(oRng)
    lRows = 0 ' Extra Rows belonging to current level
    ' find how many rows while value on row beneath greater than current
    Set oRngSP = oRng.Offset(lRows + 1, 0)
    Do While oRng.Value < oRngSP.Value And IsNumeric(oRngSP)
        lRows = lRows + 1
        Set oRngSP = oRngSP.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set oRngSP = Nothing
    ' Setup the range for SumProduct
    With Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(lRows, 0)).Offset(0, 2) ' Qty column
        If oRng.Value = oRngSP.Value - 1 Then
            oRng.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=sumproduct(" & Replace(.Address, "$", "") & "," & Replace(.Offset(0, 1).Address, "$", "") & ")"
            oRng.Offset(0, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
    End With
    Debug.Print oRng.Offset(0, 5).Address & vbTab & oRng.Offset(0, 5).Formula
    ' Move the range to next row
    Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
Set oRng = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: I don't get your example. You say the first should equal 16, yet below that you have 2 * 6 (=12) and 3 * 2 (=6) which should total 18.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Oh woops, you are totally right. That 16 should be 18 - Sum (QTY * UNIT WEIGHTS) of the child parts. I still can't get my code to sum anything though, so that will be my next problem to fix.

Comment: This is certainly easy enough to fix (I would walk the list in a different manner), but I'm headed to dinner. If someone hasn't answered when I get back, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Could you possibly put up a new screenshot of the correct math? I'm wondering how to handle row 11, where the level is 3... does that mean the item in row 11 is a child of row 10?

Comment: And then wouldn't the weight of row 10 be (10 * 3) = 30, not zero?

Comment: I updated the screenshot (hopefully everything is right this time). In row 11 where the level is 3 means it is a child of row 10 - so when row 8 Level 1 goes to sum it's children, it would only sum the level 2s and not the level 3s (since the level 2s already include the weight of its children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a column to store **SumProduct** of levels that are higher than the current level. Since there is a UnitWeight for Level 1 in your sample (row 5).

```
Sub UpdateUnitWeight()
    Const StartRow = 2
    Dim oRng As Range ' Range to work on
    Dim oRngSP As Range ' Range for SumProduct
    Dim lRows As Long ' Counter
    ' Start from row "StartRow"
    Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartRow, "A")
    ' Loop on numeric cells from StartRow
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng) Or Not IsNumeric(oRng)
        lRows = 0 ' Extra Rows belonging to current level
        ' find how many rows while value on row beneath greater than current
        Set oRngSP = oRng.Offset(lRows + 1, 0)
        Do While oRng.Value < oRngSP.Value And IsNumeric(oRngSP)
            lRows = lRows + 1
            Set oRngSP = oRngSP.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        Set oRngSP = Nothing
        ' Setup the range for SumProduct
        With Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(lRows, 0)).Offset(0, 2) ' Qty column
            oRng.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=sumproduct(" & Replace(.Address, "$", "") & "," & Replace(.Offset(0, 1).Address, "$", "") & ")"
        End With
        Debug.Print oRng.Offset(0, 5).Address & vbTab & oRng.Offset(0, 5).Formula
        ' Move the range to next row
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample Output based on yours:

[image: SampleOutput]

Formulas on the column "UpdateUnitWeight":

```
$F$2    =SUMPRODUCT(C2:C4,D2:D4)
$F$3    =SUMPRODUCT(C3,D3)
$F$4    =SUMPRODUCT(C4,D4)
$F$5    =SUMPRODUCT(C5,D5)
$F$6    =SUMPRODUCT(C6:C7,D6:D7)
$F$7    =SUMPRODUCT(C7,D7)
$F$8    =SUMPRODUCT(C8:C11,D8:D11)
$F$9    =SUMPRODUCT(C9,D9)
$F$10   =SUMPRODUCT(C10:C11,D10:D11)
$F$11   =SUMPRODUCT(C11,D11)
```

If this is not the correct logic, do you mean if there is a higher level beneath, you sum product until **a drop in the level**?

---

**SOLUTION**

Now that the goal is clear, the approach is slightly different to above. Also recommend you to store the Macro in a Module, not on that Worksheet object.

```
Sub UpdateUnitWeight() ' Solution
    Const StartRow = 2
    Dim oRng As Range ' Range to work on
    Dim oRngTmp As Range ' Temporary Range for checking
    Dim sTxt As String ' Temporary string for formula use

    ' Start from row "StartRow"
    Set oRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartRow, "A")
    ' Process all numeric cells from StartRow
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng) Or Not IsNumeric(oRng)
        ' Total Weight = Qty * Unit Weight (Level independent, applies to each row)
        oRng.Offset(0, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[-2]*rc[-1]"
        ' Unit Weight may depend on levels beneath
        ' Current level should SUM rows below that equals (current level + 1) until same level is met
        sTxt = ""
        Set oRngTmp = oRng.Offset(lRows + 1, 0)
        Do While Not IsEmpty(oRngTmp) And IsNumeric(oRngTmp)
            Select Case oRngTmp.Value - oRng.Value
                Case 1  ' if test range equals current level + 1, prepare formula (Sum of Total Weight of child)
                    sTxt = sTxt & "+" & Replace(oRngTmp.Offset(0, 4).Address, "$", "")
                Case 0
                    Exit Do
            End Select
            Set oRngTmp = oRngTmp.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        Set oRngTmp = Nothing
        ' Write the formula into the Unit Weight
        If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then oRng.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=" & sTxt
        ' Move the range to next row
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Sample Output:**

[image: FinalSolution]

Comment: I think that's really close! I updated the picture and link in the original post with a better example and I added an If statement to only sumproduct the weights of the immediate child assembly (i.e. level 1 sumproducts only the level 2s - the level 2s sumproduct the level 3s etc). Now I'm getting an "out of range error" and i'm not sure why.

Comment: @user3579146 Solution added based on your new data. Just that I don't recommend you keep unnecessary macros in the Sheet object. Should put in a separate Module. Feel free to change `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `ActiveSheet` in this case.

Comment: It's very easy for people and macro to delete the Sheet1, and hence having the macro in Module, you don't have to worry about the code. Also in Modules, it can be imported/exported. Please mark as Answer if there is no more issues.